# generalizing Merten's theorem

Tags: analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

I have to proof a generalization of merten's theorem for prime numbers and I am really stuck and can't think of the answer.

For a series of natural numbers $q_1 < q_2 < ... < q_n$ with $ q_n \sim n ~log(n)$
show that $$\sum_{q_n \leq x} \frac{1}{q_n} \sim loglogx ~ for ~ x \rightarrow \infty$$

I tried to use summation by parts like we used for the proof of merten's theorem (essentially the same statement for the series of prime numbers) but it didn't lead anywhere. I am fairly sure that it isn't actually that difficult but somehow I can't find the trick.

There is also a second part to the question and since I am really bad with examples, I hope you have some ideas:

Does the Limes $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{(\sum_{q_n \leq x} \frac{1}{q_n} - loglogx)}$$ exist? Give a proof or counter example!
(Again sure here that I have to give a counter example)

And:
Construct a series of natural numbers with $q_n \sim n~log(n)$ such that there exist natural numbers $N$, such that there is no $q_n$ with $$N^2 < q_n < (N+1)^2$$

Thanks!

Comment: Not Mr Merten but Mr Mertens

Comment: It's true for the first question, and there will always be a limit, but calculating that limit for any sequence $q_1,q_2,\cdots ,q_n$ could be problematic.

Comment: $q_n = n \ln n+ 100 n$ ,then for $N=27$ there is no $q_n$ such that $27^2 < q_n <(27+1)^2$

Comment: but for your $q_n$ it doesn't hold that $q_n \sim n log n$